# Jenkins plugin for HP ALM

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, alm, hp-quality-center

I am trying to execute QC test scripts from Jenkins groovy. Do you know any plugins which support QC execution from Jenkins?

I found HP ALM Quality Center Plugin which is not working and hp-application-automation-tools-plugin which is breaking my other builds.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Agiletestware Bumblebee](http://www.agiletestware.com/bumblebee). It supports execution of QC tests from Jenkins, but they need to be stored in QC upfront.
It also allows you to export JUnit-like test reports to HP ALM.

Disclaimer: I'm a developer of Bumblebee

Comment: But it required Bumblebee server configured before using the plugin, right? Could you please share the requirements to utilize the plugin and install Bumblebee server ?

Comment: Yes, Bumblebee server is required and it must run on Windows machine.
  Here is a link to the documentation: http://www.agiletestware.com/docs/bumblebee-docs/en/latest/
You can also get a trial license by submitting register form on this page: http://www.agiletestware.com/bumblebee-register